# How can I get (x, y) of an object in Android Studio which has been rotated?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, android-canvas

I am working on a game in Android Studio which has an object rotating around the center of the screen. My problem is that for some reason after rotating the object the x and y position have stayed the same(I am guessing because since the canvas is rotating it still has the same points in that canvas). I need the x an y coordinates in order to calculate collision detection. After realizing the x and y did not change I attempted to write a function which would calculate the x and y using basic trig but it was spitting out strange values for some reason(also attached below). My question is how do I find the x and y position of this object in the main canvas? The code is below.

```
private int x;
    private int y;

    private int rotate;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private int color = Color.rgb(226, 255, 243);

    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Player(){
        rotate = 0;
        width = Constants.width / 10;
        height = Constants.height / 50;
        x = Constants.width / 2 - width / 2;
        y = Constants.height / 2 + Constants.height / 8;
    }

    public void setRotate(int rotate){
        this.rotate = rotate;
    }
    public int getRotate(){return rotate;}

    public int getX(){return x;}
    public int getY(){return y;}
    public int getWidth(){return width;}
    public int getHeight(){return height;}

    public void update(){
        if(rotate >= 360){
            rotate = 0;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        paint.setColor(color);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(rotate, Constants.width / 2, Constants.height / 2);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

The code below is my attempt at finding the x and y coordinates but it only spits out strange values and I cant find the problem. This code is my main class.

```
        private int getPlayerX(int rotation){
        double angleA;
        double angleC;
        double sideC;
        double sideA;

        angleA = 180 - ((180 - rotation) + 90);
        sideC = Constants.width / 2 + Constants.height / 8;
        angleC = 180 - rotation;

        sideA = ((Math.sin(angleA) * sideC)) / (Math.sin(angleC));

        playerx = Constants.width / 2 + (int) sideA;

        return playerx;
    }
    private int getPlayerY(int rotation){
        double sideC;
        double angleC;
        double angleB;
        double sideB;

        sideC = Constants.width / 2 + Constants.height / 8;
        angleC = 180 - rotation;
        angleB = 90;

        sideB = sideC * (Math.sin(angleB)) / (Math.sin(angleC));

        playery = Constants.height + (int) sideB;

        return playery;
    }
```

Comment: use `android.graphics.Matrix` API

Comment: It rotates the object but still keeps the x and y in the same place, just like with the canvas.rotate(); function.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?  rotate the canvas,  then draw something, then ...?

Comment: did you try Matrix#map* methods?

Comment: I was trying to rotate the object around the center and then find the new x and y points after the rotation. I was finally able to do it with the Matrix Map methods. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: btw, you dont need `canvas.rotate`, instead rotate your `Matrix`, then call `Canvas#concat`, then draw your stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try to look to matrices. This is the better practice to define transformation of an object.
Look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix
Example:

```
public Player(){
   //...
   //matrix 3x3 with all transformations you need
   Matrix3f m;

   void rotate(float angle) {
       Matrix3f rot = new Matrix3f();
       rot.data = {cos(angle), -sin(angle), 0.0,
                   sin(angle), cos(angle), 0.0,
                   0.0,        0.0,        1.0 }
       m.Multiply(rot);  
   }

   //get the world position of a local point
   vec2f getWorld(vec2f inPt) {
       vec3f p = vec3f(inPt.x, inPt.y, 1.0);
       p = m.Transform(p);
       return vec2f(p.x, p.y);
   }

   //get the local position of a world point
   vec2f getLocal(vec2f inPt) {
       Matrix3f invM = m.Invert();
       vec3f p = vec3f(inPt.x, inPt.y, 1.0);
       p = invM.Transform(p);
       return vec2f(p.x, p.y);
   }
```

Classes Matrix3f, vec3f, vec2f with methods Transform, Invert, Multiply and so on you should provide by yourself (you can find a lot of code samples in the network)

Comment: I have been trying to implement rotations using matrices but I am still getting the same problem, the x and y position do not change, and I dont understand the code above. When I try to use it in my code I get a million and one errors???

Comment: This code is the sample of what you can do with matrices. Look to the link in my previous post and study this question by yourself. If you dont understand it by yourself nobody helps you. I believe that there are a lot of open source game engines in the network (unity for example). Try to use them. If you want to write the engine by self that is good chose but you need to learn some basic things. Matrices are one of them. Good luck. If you want i'll write the implementation of classes that i used in my previous post but i think the better way to learn the question is write it by self